# When you buy a big good part at wholesale price

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

Imagine you buy 10,000 T-shirts wholesale. Then someone asks you how much did you pay for this good part? You would say:

> - I purchased all this stuff ***at wholesale prices***.
> - I purchased all this stuff ***at a wholesale price***.
> - I purchased all this stuff ***at the wholesale price***.

Which one of the above structures is more common / grammatically correct / natural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colloquial and idiomatic:  *I paid wholesale.* or *I got it wholesale*.  Just as you say in your first sentence: **Imagine you buy 10,000 T-shirts wholesale.**

More formal:

*I purchased this lot of T-shirts **at the wholesale price**.*

If you buy several lots, or lots of different items:

*I purchased these items **at wholesale prices**.*

Comment: One might reasonably expect that there are several wholesale prices for different lot sizes, for example 25LE each for 100, 20LE each for 1000, 15LE each for 10,000. I would therefore respectfully suggest that **a** wholesale price would be more appropriate than **the**, as the price you paid  is one of many wholesale prices.

Comment: I wasn't taking the T-shirt example literally. It could just as well have been ounces of gold. **the wholesale price** could be used to refer to *the going price* of something on the open wholesale market; **a wholesale price** would have the more general meaning, "wholesale" (not retail), suggesting that the wholesale price varied, or that there was no going price as the item was not being traded like a commodity.